# How to add id of article using addButtonFromModelFunction in Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to add a Preview button in Article. This button shows a front-end preview page.

In App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleCrudController.php

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromModelFunction('line', 'openpreview', 'openPreview',
'beginning');
```

In App\Models\Article.php

```
public function openPreview($crud)
{
    return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" target="_blank" href="' 
    . url('/preview/') . '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview the page">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Preview</a>';
}
```

Now I am not sure how to add article slugs to each article.

Answer (score 1):

`$crud->slug` worked for me.

```
public function openPreview($crud)
{
    return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" target="_blank" href="' . url('/preview/' . $crud->slug) . '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview the page"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Preview</a>';
}
```